# Prepopulate WFFM field with username

Tags: wffm, membership-provider, rules-engine

I would like to use the rules engine to prepopulate a WFFM form field with the logged in user's username. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work, even though the conditions and actions that I am using are provided out of the box.

I don't see any errors in my logs or at runtime - the field value is just not being set.

If you look at the below screenshot of the form designer, the rule that I am using is at the bottom left.

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here or if there is something special that I need to do in order to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure the field that you need is UserName? Can you check (with a debugger or so) which fields you have in your profile and whether UserName is filled?

Comment: `UserName` is the out of the box property on the `UserProfile` that contains the username. I can't check with a debugger, as I don't have access to ReSharper or Reflector on the machine that I'm currently working from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this blog post](https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blog-posts/using_xprofile_data_to_populate_a_wffm_part_1) the only valid options are `Comment`, `Name` and `Full Name`. You can try changing your value from `User Name` to `Full Name` but I'm not sure if it will give you what you need. You may need to create a very simple custom field for this, or alternatively create a custom rule action as per the linked article.

Comment: Custom rule action it is!